# improving speed of this numpy-based diffraction calculator

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy

I'm going to simulate diffraction patterns of a normal incident gaussian profile beam from a 2D array of point scatterers with a distribution in heights.

The 2D array of scatterer positions `X`, `Y` and `Z` each have size `N x N` and these are summed-over in each call to `E_ab(a, b, positions, w_beam)`. This is done `M x M` times to build up the diffraction pattern.

If I estimate ten floating point operations per scatter site per pixel and a nanosecond per flop (what my laptop does for small numpy arrays) I'd expect the time to be `10 M^2 N^2 1E-09` seconds. For small N this runs a factor of 50 or 100 slower than that, and for large `N` (larger than say 2000) it slows down even further. I am guessing these have something to do with the paging of the large arrays in memory.

What can I do to increase the speed for large `N`?

**note:** Right now the height variation `Z` is random, in the future I plan to include an additional systematic height variation term as well, so even though purely gaussian variation might have an analytical solution, I need to do this numerically.

---

Since I'm distributing Z height randomly here, plots will look a little different each time. My output (run on a laptop) is as follows, and I can not even begin to understand why it takes longer (~ 16 seconds) when `w_beam` is small than when it is large (~6 seconds). (When I run this on an older Python 2 that came with IDLE all four are between 10 and 10.5 seconds)

My estimator `10 M^2 N^2 1E-09` suggests 0.25 seconds, these are roughly 50 times slower so there may be room for substantial improvement.

```
1 16.460583925247192
2 14.861294031143188
4 8.405776023864746
8 6.4988932609558105
```

**Total time:** about 46 seconds on 2012 MacBook and recent Anaconda Python 3 installation.

Python script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

def E_ab(a, b, positions, w_beam, k0):
    X, Y, Z = positions
    Rsq = X**2 + Y**2
    phases = k0 * (a*X + b*Y + (1 + np.sqrt(1 - a**2 - b**2))*Z)
    E = np.exp(-Rsq/w_beam**2)  * np.exp(-j*phases)
    return E.sum() / w_beam**2 # rough normalization

twopi, j = 2*np.pi, np.complex(0, 1)

wavelength = 0.08
k0  = twopi/wavelength

z_noise = 0.05 * wavelength

N, M = 100, 50
x = np.arange(-N, N+1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)
Z = z_noise * np.random.normal(size=X.shape) # use random Z noise for now
positions = [X, Y, Z]

A = np.linspace(0, 0.2, M)

answers = []
for w_beam in (1, 2, 4, 8):
    E = []
    tstart = time.time()
    for i, a in enumerate(A):
        EE = []
        for b in A:
            e = E_ab(a, b, positions, w_beam, k0)
            EE.append(e)
        E.append(EE)
    print(w_beam, time.time() - tstart)
    answers.append(np.array(E))

if True:
    plt.figure()
    for i, E in enumerate(answers):
        plt.subplot(2, 2, i+1)
        plt.imshow(np.log10(np.abs(E)), vmin=0.0001)
        plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
```

[image: plot of a diffraction pattern]

Comment: Is `k0` supposed to be a global? It is used in `E_ab` but not passes as an argument.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist either way is okay with me but your way would be better so I've made `k0` an argument.

Comment: It probably takes longer for small `w_beam`, because the exponent in `np.exp(-Rsq/w_beam**2)` is larger and takes longer to compute.

Comment: @Graipher ah that makes sense! I was thinking "but they're all small numbers, almost zero" but forgot to think about how they got that way. Interestingly my Python 2 uses numpy version 1.13.0 and all four times are between 10 and 11 seconds (reproducibly) while my Python 3 Anaconda installation with numpy version 1.17.3 shows the times from 16 to 6 seconds as shown. I'll be surprised if `np.exp()` has changed, doesn't it call some transcendental functions built into my laptop's CPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make your script a bit faster. See the comments in the
source code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

# Makes it so numpy always outputs the same random numbers which is
# useful during development. Comment out the line in production.
np.random.seed(1234)

def main():
    twopi, img = 2*np.pi, np.complex(0, 1)

    wavelength = 0.08
    k0  = twopi/wavelength

    z_noise = 0.05 * wavelength

    N, M = 100, 50
    x = np.arange(-N, N+1)

    # Use random Z noise for now
    Z = z_noise * np.random.normal(size = (x.shape[0], x.shape[0]))

    A = np.linspace(0, 0.2, M)

    tstart = time.time()
    answers = []

    # X and Y with shapes (x, 1) and (1, x) contains the same data.
    X = x[np.newaxis,:]
    Y = x[:,np.newaxis]

    # Compute squared Euclidean distances with shape (x, x).
    Rsq = X**2 + Y**2

    # Compute other distances with shape (M, M).
    a = A[:,np.newaxis]
    b = A[np.newaxis,:]
    SQ = 1 + np.sqrt(1 - a**2 - b**2)

    # Add noise thing (M, M, x, x).
    SQ_Z = SQ[:,:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis] * Z

    # Gets shape (M, 1, x) and (M, x, 1).
    A_X = A[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis] * X
    A_Y = A[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis] * Y

    # Calculates A*X + A*Y with shape (M, M, x, x).
    A_X_Y = A_X[:,np.newaxis] + A_Y[np.newaxis,:]

    # e^{-j*phases} with shape (M, M, x, x).
    A_stuff = np.exp(-img * k0 * (A_X_Y + SQ_Z))
    for w_beam in (1, 2, 4, 8):
        coeff = np.exp(-Rsq/w_beam**2)
        # Sums over the last two dimensions, shape becomes (M, M).
        E = np.sum(A_stuff * coeff, axis = (2, 3)) / w_beam**2
        answers.append(E)

    print(f'Time: {time.time() - tstart:.3}')
    # Print checksum. Useful for debugging.
    print(sum(np.sum(E) for e in answers))
    if True:
        plt.figure()
        for i, E in enumerate(answers):
            plt.subplot(2, 2, i+1)
            plt.imshow(np.log10(np.abs(E)), vmin=0.0001)
            plt.colorbar()
        plt.show()

main()
```

I have wrapped all your code in a `main` function. It is good practice
to do so, even for small scripts, but it makes it easy to see if
there's any dependencies on global variables.

The script runs about four times faster. Most of the speedup comes
from replacing your explicit loop with vector functions. So instead of

```
for i, a in enumerate(A):
    EE = []
    for b in A:
        e = E_ab(a, b, positions, w_beam, k0)
        EE.append(e)
    E.append(EE)
```

those lines now read

```
coeff = np.exp(-Rsq/w_beam**2)
E = np.sum(A_stuff * coeff, axis = (2, 3)) / w_beam**2
answers.append(E)
```

To get the data in a format that vector functions can handle I've
added a lot of
[broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). It
can be used to compute, for example, the [cartesian
product](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10748/cartesian-products-in-numpy)
of arbitrary numpy arrays.

I think someone who understands the math (which I don't) could
optimize your script even more. Some of the calculations seem
redundant to me, but I have no idea how to factor them out.

Comment: I did a quick test and I'm wondering what time you got when you say "a bit faster" because this is *far slower* on my laptop (2012 MacBook). Total execution time is now 116 seconds and that breaks down to 29.6 seconds of overhead before the loop, and then the four loops through `w_beam` are 9.6, 8.4, 30.9 and 37.5 seconds. My version runs in 47.7 second total, with the four times shown in the question (and no overhead). Could you mention the "faster" time that you obtained and some information on the computer used? As I mention in the question I think my speed is limited by memory paging.

Comment: Odd. I'm benchmarking by running the script and not doing anything else with the computer. With N=100, your version runs in 35s and mine in 7s and with N=200, yours in 140s and mine in 29s. Perhaps you're using an old version of Numpy which doesn't do broadcasting as well? My Numpy version is 1.17.4.

Comment: see [this comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/235200/improving-speed-of-this-numpy-based-diffraction-calculator/235222#comment460295_235200) for my Numpy versions. I get similar total times in 1.17.3 and the older 1.13.0 (in Python 2). But things can still suddenly change [as in this SciPy update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49428804/3904031) . I'll look into updating from 1.17.3 to 1.17.4 tomorrow; I'll feel safer being around some developers when I try.

Comment: The running time will probably depend on your available memory and CPU L1 cache size, since in the OP only an M x N array had to be kept in memory, but here it is an M x N x 50 x 50 array, 50 being the default number of values produced by `linspace`.

Comment: @Graipher yes I think that the larger array combined with my laptop (including CPU) being circa 2012 and having low remaining disk space might be why this is so much slower for me on this particular computer.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist I've just had a friend run on numpy 1.13.1 and it's much faster than my 1.17.3, so once I move to a better computer I expect to be able to take advantage of this. Thanks!

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist example of a performance hit for swapping pieces of large arrays in and out of cache. Paging slows things down tremendously!  [How large is my 2012 MacBook Air's L1 cache? Are they larger now?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/379323/143729)

Comment: If the array is large enough that it causes swapping, then that explains why it runs slower. However, with N = 100, M = 50, the size is "only" about 1.6 GB which should be fine if you have 4 GB of memory. You can try and reduce the parameters to see if you can find some "cliff" where performance starts to suffer. Or you can use single precision math by adding `dtype = 'f4'` to all array constructors. That roughly halves the execution time on my computer but the simulation accuracy may suffer.